# Finding Member Position in a JS Object

Tags: javascript, object

What would be the quickest way to find the position of a member in a JS object?

Let's say I have the following object:

```
var myObject = {
    "apple": { "color" : "green", "shape" : "round" },
    "banana": { "color" : "yellow", "shape" : "long" },
    "orange": { "color" : "orange", "shape" : "round" },
    "kiwi": { "color" : "green", "shape" : "round" }
}
```

Now, if I want to know the position of banana (i.e. 2), do I need to loop through the object or is there a quicker way?

Update:

Thanks to everyone, I now understand that there is no concept of "order" in an object and I cannot reliably find a position of a member.  Neither do I have the possibility to find the next or previous member.  That all makes perfect sense...

So the way I solved my issue is this:  I looped through my array and fed the keys to an array that I can use to keep track of the members I have in the object.

```
var fruits = new Array();
for (var key in myObject) {
    fruits.push(key);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects in JavaScript aren't ordered.  What exactly do you want to do with this data once you get it?  Because if you're looking for the 2nd value in the object, you may not always get the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense...  I really don't care about the order, I just want to find the previous and next members in the object. Can I assume the members maintain the same order during the lifetime of this object? Because I don't care if the order is different the next time I create the object, as long as I can figure out which comes before and after a particular member.

Comment: Objects don't have an order, so 'previous' and 'next' don't make sense here.  I suggest using an array (of objects), so can easily get their order.

Answer (score 12):

i do it this way

```
var position = Object.keys(myObject).indexOf('banana');
```

maybe it helps others...

Answer (score 4):

Technically, "banana" doesn't have a set position. You're using a JavaScript object to store your data which doesn't guarantee any order. If order is important, you should store things in an Array. You would have to do something like:

```
var myObjectArray = [
    { 'key' : 'apple', 'value' : { 'color' : 'green', 'shape' : 'round' } },
    { 'key' : 'banana', 'value' : { 'color' : 'yellow', 'shape' : 'long' } },
    { 'key' : 'orange', 'value' : { 'color' : 'orange', 'shape' : 'round' } },
    { 'key' : 'kiwi', 'value' : { 'color' : 'green', 'shape' : 'round' } }
]
```

And then to get the index:

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i < myObjectArray.length; i++){
    if(myObjectArray[i].key === 'banana'){
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  Sadly I am stuck with the format of the object I get and can't change it to an array. :(

Comment: @Steve - You can always write your own translation to make new objects with the format that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't rely on object keys having a strong ordering. It's not guaranteed by the spec, and some previous versions of Chrome didn't perserve ordering, for example.

Depending on your use case, you could either store the index, or you could keep an array around

```
var myObject = { 
   apple: { index:0, color:"green" ...

var myKeys = ["apple", "banana", ... ]
var myObject = ...
```

Comment: This is called an "object", JavaScript does't have "associative arrays".

Comment: @Rocket I changed my answer to avoid confusion, but I hate the semantic distinction. That one "considered harmful essay" that popularized this distinction is a bunch of fluff that boils down to "don't use for/in loops because prototypes can be modified" and "there's no point in using new Array()"

Comment: Huh?  There's a distinction because objects and arrays are 2 completely different things.  `{a:b}` isn't an array, it can just be accessed like one using `[]`.  `for...in` is bad because what if I do `Object.prototype.test=3` (which is why should use `hasOwnProperty`)?  `new Array` is ok, but `[]` is better (and may be faster).

Comment: And associative arrays and arrays are 2 completely different things too. hence, "semantics". I just realized that you come from PHP land, where apparently they are the same thing. Sorry if that's causing some confusion. And I completely agree with the two principles of that article. but 'for/in' is bad in general, unless you check specifically with hasownproperty, because all it takes is some idiot modifying Object.prototype to break your code again.

Comment: I do both PHP and JavaScript.  I just didn't want you to confuse others reading this with the "wrong" terms.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array It's not the wrong term. It just happens to be confusing to PHP developers.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting.  Didn't know that the term was correct.  Thanks. :-P